# Error in setting up server through express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

This is my server.js file and I get the error mentioned below when I am trying to set up the server using Express.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

 var PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

 app.all('/*', function(req, res) {
    res.send('<!DOCTYPE html> <head> <title> Todo App </title> </head> <body> <h1>This is a Todo App </h1> </body> </html>');
});

app.listen(PORT, function() {
    //callback
    console.log('Server running on ' + PORT);
});
```

This is the error i am getting

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { ??v
                                                          ^
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:528:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:590:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
```

Comment: why `res.send('\\` with backslash ? try with `res.send('hi');` if it is working then try to fix your html.

Comment: `Invalid or unexpected token` normally means a syntax error.

Comment: @UnknownUser that came in as part of editting the question i dont have it my code though

Comment: I'm running the same code and that is working :P i think you are doing some mistake. silly one :P

Answer (score 0):

I have no problem running this bunch of code after improving the formatting and removed those "`" in the code.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

 var PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

 app.all('/*', function(req, res) {
    res.send('\
        <!DOCTYPE html>\
            <head>\
                <title> Todo App </title>\
            </head>\
            <body>\
                 <h1>This is a Todo App </h1>\
            </body>\
       </html>\
    ');
});

app.listen(PORT, function() {
    //callback
    console.log('Server running on ' + PORT);
});
```

**NOTE**: you declared `PORT` variable but you used `port` variable instead in `app.listen()`.

Comment: i am still getting the same error . I have everything perfectly set up for running a node server

Comment: You can try something like @Soviut said. Just send a `'hello'` to ensure that the server run perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is most likely based around the formatting of your multiline HTML string. Try sending something simpler like `'hello'` to make sure it works. Then work your way forward by adding a few tags at a time until you find where the error is.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send('hello');
});
```

Finally, you should really consider using a templating system like [Pug](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html) or use [`res.sendFile()`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile) to return separate html files rather than trying to build raw HTML strings. The escaping you need to do on the raw strings will be incredibly difficult to debug since they're just strings so the javascript engine doesn't know what line they're faulting on.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  // __dirname will resolve to your project folder
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
});
```

Comment: And you tried with `/` instead of `/*` for your route?

Comment: @Soviut `/*` is not a problem

Comment: @VikramPrasad Can you make sure that your code is exactly same as image https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBRVn.png

Comment: @VikramPrasad and how you are running your node application ?

Comment: @VikramPrasad  use `node server` remove `.js`

Comment: you are missing something that is creating problem. proofread your js once again.

Comment: It will be better if @VikramPrasad can screenshot his code and upload the image here. The code seems to be perfectly fine for us.

Comment: @DylanLaw i have shared the screenshots please look into it.

Comment: @VikramPrasad have you restarted your script after making each change? Node doesn't automatically reload scripts when they change.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It was caused by file coding. I mean I create `server.js` file by powershell command `'' >> server.js` then I saw that error but when I created file by IDE with the same content error disappear.

Answer (score 0):

I think to answer your question we need more information about your environment and what versions of things you are using:

```
 node -v # v6.11.1
 npm -v # 3.10.10
```

Here are the literal steps I did on Mac OS and bash and was successful

```
$ mkdir test-express
$ cd test-express
$ npm install express
$ cat <<EOF > index.js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.all('/*', function(req, res) {
    res.send('<!DOCTYPE html> <head> <title> Todo App </title> </head> <body> <h1>This is a Todo App </h1> </body> </html>');
});

app.listen(PORT, function() {
    //callback
    console.log('Server running on ' + PORT);
});
EOF
$ node index.js
Server running on 3000
```

And the curl:

```
$ curl localhost:3000
<!DOCTYPE html> <head> <title> Todo App </title> </head> <body> <h1>This is a Todo App </h1> </body> </html>
```